# how to select the most frequently appearing values?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've seen examples where the query orders by count and takes the top row, but in this case there can be multiple "most frequent" values, so I might want to return more than just a single result.

In this case I want to find the most frequently appearing last names in a users table, here's what I have so far:

```
select last_name from users group by last_name having max(count(*));
```

Unfortunately with this query I get an error that my max function is nested too deeply.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
select
  x.last_name,
  x.name_count
from
  (select
    u.last_name,
    count(*) as name_count,
    rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rank
  from
    users u
  group by
    u.last_name) x
where
  x.rank = 1
```

Use the analytical function `rank`. It will assign a numbering based on the order of `count(*) desc`. If two names got the same count, they get the same rank, and the next number is skipped (so you might get rows having ranks 1, 1 and 3). `dense_rank` is an alternative which doesn't skip the next number if two rows got the same rank, (so you'd get 1, 1, 2), but if you want only the rows with rank 1, there is not much of a difference.

If you want only one row, you'd want each row to have a different number. In that case, use `row_number`. Apart from this small-but-important difference, these functions are similar and can be used in the same way.

Comment: I believe this answer is incorrect re: dense rank. dense rank would still return both numbers at the top, it would just not skip the next rank numbers.

row_number would not include both numbers together.

Comment: @MikeS Thanks! You're right, and I don't know where I was with my mind when I wrote it. `rank` and `dense_rank` both can return the same number for multiple rows, if they are 'equal' according to the specified sorting. I've corrected the text.

Answer (score 6):

```
select name
from
   (select name, count(1) 
      from table
      group by name
      order by count(1) desc) a
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation